# Two or many Android Applications on a local network (wifi) communicate to a single database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need idea to create a POS solution for multiple counters on a shop in  android which will be accessing a single database that can be in any of APK installed on the network or the stand alone SQLite Database.

My Idea is to have a application which holds db and the other application should access that DB.

Is it possible in Android? Please suggest the best possible solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is [not intended](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-it-possible-to-use-sqlite-as-a-client-server-database) to be used as a client-server database. It is simply not built for highly concurrent operations. SQLite works well in simpler scenarios as stated [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). So, you would probably need a dedicated database server such as MySQL or Oracle that is hosted separately in the network.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* wanted to do this, you're going to have to handle any concurrency behaviours yourself.

However, your best bet is to do exactly what you've said:

One (master) device holds the database. It accepts signals from the other devices, and allows them to (potentially) query (or alter) the database's contents.

In order to do so, you'll need to handle:

- Some means by which the devices will discover the master device. In Android 4.1 there is a Network Service Discovery API for this:  http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html The master device would advertise the service to the others.
- The devices might be able to use this Peer-to-Peer API to communicate: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html
- Once you've established a connection, you'll also need to create a vocabulary of commands which the clients can send to the master device, and a means of dispatching those requests.

This specific case *does* seem like it might be better suited to having a "real PC" acting as the hub with a more robust application stack (e.g. Postgres or even MySQL, more options for network server tools and administration, faster/more storage options, et al.)